# React: Convert CSSProperties to Styled-Component

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I have an object in following format:

```js
    let style:React.CSSProperties|object = {
        marginLeft: '0',
        borderRadius: '20px',
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    }
```

I need to convert the React CSSProperties into corresponding string format for instance:

```js
    let string_styles:string = `{
        margin-left: 0;
        border-radius: 20px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }`
```

since I can't find a tangible syntax to write css such as `:hover`, `::before`, `::before:hover` inline, the purpose use it as a styled component for now, meanwhile leave the CSSProperties object alone for future import.

inelegantly, I hard coded the transforming method.

```
    deQuote(dict:object):string{
        return JSON.stringify(dict).replace(/['"]+/g, '');
    }
    // passin: {marginLeft: '0', borderRadius: '20px'} 
    // return: `{marginLeft: 0, borderRadius: 20px}`

    deBraces(str:string):string{
        return str.substring(1, str.length-1);
    }
    // passin: `{marginLeft: 0, borderRadius: 20px}`
    // return: `marginLeft: 0, borderRadius: 20px`

    deComma(str:string):string{
        return str.split(',').join(';');
    }
    // passin: `marginLeft: 0, borderRadius: 20px`
    // return: `marginLeft: 0; borderRadius: 20px`

    deBase(dict:object):string{
        return deComma(deBraces(deQuote(dict)));
    }
    // passin: {marginLeft: '0', borderRadius: '20px'} 
    // return: `marginLeft: 0; borderRadius: 20px`
```

But here comes the part that is tricky, it takes lot of effort to convert

```
    marginLeft -> margin-left
```

---

## Solved by customised function,

```
    CSSPropertiesToComponent(dict:React.CSSProperties){
        let str = '';
        for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(dict)){
            let clo = '';
            key.split('').forEach(lt=>{
                if(lt.toUpperCase() === lt){
                    clo += '-' + lt.toLowerCase();
                }else{
                    clo += lt;
                }
            });
            str += clo + ':' + value + ';';
        }
        return str;
    }
```

However, if there is a better way to convert React.CSSProperties into Styled Component string, please let me know.

Comment: https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#pseudoelements-pseudoselectors-and-nesting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why you need to convert your object to string?

You can map through it and build your final string by using `Object.keys` and `Array.reduce` methods.

```js
const style = {
    marginLeft: '0',
    borderRadius: '20px',
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center',
}

const finalResult = Object.keys(style).reduce((accumulator, key) => {
    // transform the key from camelCase to kebab-case
    const cssKey = kebabCase(key)
    // remove ' in value
    const cssValue = style[key].replace("'", "")
    // build the result
    // you can break the line, add indent for it if you need
    return `${accumulator}${cssKey}:${cssValue};`
}, '')
```

If you don't want to use kebabCase library, you can use a simple regex to find all upper case and convert it to lower case with `-` before it.

```js
const regex = new RegExp(/[A-Z]/g)
const kebabCase = (str) => str.replace(regex, v => `-${v.toLowerCase()}`)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`lodash.kebabCase`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.kebabcase) [package](https://bundlephobia.com/result?p=lodash.kebabcase) to solve that exact problem.

Here is an example

```js
import kebabCase from 'lodash.kebabcase';

kebabCase('Foo Bar');
// => 'foo-bar'
 
kebabCase('fooBar');
// => 'foo-bar'
 
kebabCase('__FOO_BAR__');
// => 'foo-bar'
```

Comment: I have a similar method, I am really looking forward to an easier solution. ```deCap(str:string):string{return str.split('').map(lt=>lt.match(/[A-Z]/) && lt ? `-${lt.toLowerCase()}` : lt).join('');}```
Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @duck  the easier solution is using the existing version that has been tested and used by thousands of developers over a long period. Use LoDash.